# Android SDK can't fetch XML and ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in Project Run

Tags: android

I have two problems with android SDK.The first is that after installing sdk manager I can not install new plateform,tools,sysimage etc online it gives following error:

> Fetching 
>   Validate XML
>   XML verification failed for .
>   Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <>.
>   Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>   Fetching URL: 
>   Validate XML: 
>   XML verification failed for .
>   Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <>.
>   Fetching URL: 
>   Validate XML: 
>   Failed to fetch URL , reason: addon.xml
>   Done loading packages.

- I tried force https.
- http in place of https.

I am using DSL for internet and *not using any proxy to connect to internet*.
For the sake of removing this problem I also tried proxy server but all in vain.

**So I installed all the updates offline APD v2 helped me with downloading.**

I used both Eclipse and Netbeans for dev.Everything worked fine,until I tried to run a new project and even sample project.

On Eclipse it gave me following error:

[image]

Same problem was with netbeans:

> Creating redLight-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
>   D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.: 
>   com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

I am new in android app development and trying to rebuild my Java Application for android platform,but I am stuck in first step.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your first problem is simple : Line -१:-१, it shows u r language for windows os is set to hindi (IN_HI).
 Goto Control panel region & language option change language to English for all formats.
Restart machine & fetch xml.

I am also facing second problem solution to that is not yet found
check this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/BvO5g6RMamo

Also I have updated bug in Android issues :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28824

Comment: thank you for your response,keep me updated about the second one please.

Comment: for second problem create any new project with test project option selected. this will compile & run the android app. After this u can able to run any project without created test project.